# Check user authentication by comparing html pages

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am building a crawler to perform the login in many websites and I am using Python with Selenium to automate things.

Now I come to the point in which I need to understand if my login event has succeed or not. The problem is easy to solve if you have just one website and you know the HTML code i.e. IDs attribute, names, etc.. but here I have many websites and I need to find some heuristic that tells me **in general** if the authentication has succeed.

Until now I create the following Python method:

```
def is_authenticated(self, before_event, after_event):

    auth_prob = 0.  # probability of success

    if self.username in after_event:
        auth_prob += .3

    if 'logout' in after_event.lower():
        auth_prob += .3

    return auth_prob
```

And that gives me a probability of success according to some heuristics i.e:

1. Is my username in the HTML code after the event?
2. Is "logout" contained?

This seems to work. But I would like to make things more **robust** by comparing the two html pages after the event i.e. *before_event* and *after_event*.

So, are there some measures that tells me the "degree of difference" between two strings? Or can you suggest me some other heuristic?

Answer (score 0):

I have not written any webscrapers myself, but i have come across threads stating that building a webscraper based on `selenium webdriver` is considered a bad idea. 
That being said, you can think in terms of how the client <-> server knows that they have done (successful) authentication when HTTP is stateless - i can think of `cookies`, `sessions` and `cache`, you can access all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is the best solution available unless you know per site which part of the site is restricted. If you would know that you could check for `403 Access denied` or redirects to a log-in page. There is no uniform pattern that you can check for, and even if there was, a lot of web applications will not follow the *official* pattern anyway.

Besides what you're doing, you could also check for cookies or localstorage entries that suggest a log-in.